# Add new key/value to all the existing records in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Let say I have an array like the following:

```
$list[] = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 4);
$list[] = array('a' => 2, 'b' => 5);
$list[] = array('a' => 3, 'b' => 6);
```

Is it possible to add a new `Key & Value` like `c => null` to all the array elements, but **WITHOUT** looping through all records or using `map` like functions?

The end result should be something similar to this:

```
$list[] = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 4, 'c' => null);
$list[] = array('a' => 2, 'b' => 5, 'c' => null);
$list[] = array('a' => 3, 'b' => 6, 'c' => null);
```

Actually, I'm thinking of making the second array on-the-fly and combine it to the original one, or simply looping through the array and extend it, however, just wondering if there is any better alternative way for doing that.

Comment: when all the values of C are the same what's the point?

Comment: Any reason you don't like both `foreach` and `array_map`/`array_walk`?

Comment: I think at some level you have to loop through the array, it's unavoidable.

Comment: @Passerby just looking for a proper way, a better way ... just learning new stuff!

Comment: @Mahdi `foreach`/`array_map`/`array_walk` **IS** the proper way.

Comment: @Passerby well, I hope somebody add this new ability to php 6 or even 7! I don't want to loop through records, just for adding an extra key ...

Comment: name a language this is done in without a loop?

Comment: @Dagon `SQL`: `SELECT a,b,'STATIC' AS ...` :)

Comment: @Dagon in principle it's same somehow, it isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shamelessly:

```
array_walk($list, function(&$v){ $v['c'] = null; });
```

---

**Okay further to comments**

If you are worried about the structure of your array and wish certain keys to be present even if they are not explicitly defined then you are trying to describe something specific - in which case you are better defining that object in a class - from both a readability and itegrity standpoint.

For example:

```
class MyObject {
  public $a; 
  public $b; 
  public $c;
  function __construct(){
     // this line is lazy but it's just a demo
     list($a,$b,$c) = func_get_args();
     $this->a = $a;
     $this->b = $b;
     $this->c = $c;
  }
}

$list[] = new MyObject(1, 4);
$list[] = new MyObject(2, 5);
$list[] = new MyObject(3, 6);

print_r($list);
```

[run code](http://ideone.com/duP9Jf)

In this instance - if we do not specify ***"c"*** in the constructor - it is still implicitly set as *null*.  As a consequence you do not need to loop through the `$list` array again afterwards.  Though for completeness I should probably point out here that there is possibly a speed-memory trade-off.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MyObject Object
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 4
            [c] => 
        )

    [1] => MyObject Object
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 
        )

    [2] => MyObject Object
        (
            [a] => 3
            [b] => 6
            [c] => 
        )

 )
```

---

Comment: thanks, but I'm aware of that. If you look at the question you will see that I clearly mention that I'm looking for an alternative way, but thanks anyways!

Comment: @Mahdi There is no alternative - that's the point.  At some level the system has to loop through an array - it's the whole point it exists as a language construct.  The nice thing about `array_walk` though is simply the fact that it's handled internally.

Comment: @Mahdi On a further constructive note though - If you are in a position where you need to describe an object with a default value then perhaps you should be looking to define a [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)?  That way *null* could be set implicitly on instantiation instead of having to loop through afterwards?

Comment: Why it's better to define a class? for example how it fits in my example?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I like your idea however I think it will add too much overhead to the run-time, but thanks again for the explanations and code as well :)

Comment: @Mahdi The example is purely conceptual - obviously over the top for *$a, $b, $c* and of course it depends on the scale of the application but you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this without walking through the array, either explicitly through a for loop, or implicitly using array_walk or similar

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I will wait to see how many dudes up-vote your answer! :D